# Is main form an fsMDIForm

Tags: forms, delphi, mdi

I need a way to figure out if my application's mainform is an fsMDIForm.

How can this be done?

Comment: @David: Maybe he is writing a utilities unit that can be part of *any* application? It's like `IsConsole` (perhaps).

Comment: @andreas I took "my application" to mean just that but perhaps you are right

Comment: My 'problem' is that I have some standardforms (About, DB setup and so on) that I use in many apps - when the app is MDI the form has to be moveable only inside the MDI but if it is used in a non MDI app it should be able to move on the whole screen.
So that is why I need to check and see if the main form is a fsMDIForm.

Answer (score 9):

You can test `Application.MainForm.FormStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to know for the main form of another process (other then the calling application), then if you have the handle of that main form, use:

```
MDIActive := FindWindowEx(MainFormHandle, 0, PAnsiChar('MDICLIENT'), nil) <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a function

```
function GetMovementArea: TRect;
var
  MovementRect: TRect;
begin
  if Application.MainForm.FormStyle = fsMDIForm then
    Windows.GetWindowRect(Application.MainForm.ClientHandle, MovementRect)
  else
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, @MovementRect, 0);
  Result := MovementRect;
end;
```

This return a TRect in which my form may move around

Comment: There is no need for the local variable!

Comment: You've used the exact solution provided by Andreas. Any reason why you wouldn't accept his answer?